# Add nstextattachment with ability to add text inside it in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

We want to provide a block with a curved border & background color inside UITextView, inside which user can add text, and it automatically expands based on amount of text.

Here is an image
[This is a block quote that expands when you keep going to lines, with a border & rounded corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tasjq.png)

Tried using NSAttributedString to add a background color behind the text, but that doesn't solve the problem. Need an already created block with background & rounded corners inside which the user can input text.

Also tried NSTextAttachment, but unable to figure out how to add text inside an attachment and how to increase/decrease its height automatically as new lines are created.

Comment: What specifically are you having a problem with? Have you made an attempt? Show your code with the error/bug.

Comment: @Magnas I used NSAttributedString to add background to certain text, but I need a block inside which the user can type and has rounded corners. Update the question to explain in detail.

Comment: updated* the question

Comment: NSTextAttachment don't go "under" a text, so you shouldn't be able to do so.

Comment: @Larme is there a way to do this using CoreText or by adding subviews inside UITextView maybe?